# Chrome not loading JS associated with the min.js and map file

Tags: google-chrome, gruntjs, gulp-uglify

I'm minifying with gulp.

For some reason when I look at the Sources tab under Sources menu item I see the min.js but not the js file that is referenced in the map.

On the Network tab I see that both the min.js and the min.js.map files load but they don't seem to be associated in the debugger so that I can set breakpoints on them.

When I minify with grunt everything seems to work as expected.

Any ideas?  Is there anything I can post?